# What are the "glass coffins"? What does "there's lights out, then there's lock up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, comprehension

> All the rowboats in the paintings
>   They keep trying to row away
>   And the captains' worried faces
>   Stay contorted and staring at the waves
>   They'll keep hanging in their gold frames
>   For forever, forever and a day
>   All the rowboats in the oil paintings
>   They keep trying to row away, row away
>
> Hear them whispering French and German
>   Dutch, Italian, and Latin
>   When no one's looking I catch a sculpture marble,
>   Cold, and soft as satin
>
> But the most special are the most lonely
>   God, I pity the violins
>   In **glass coffins** they keep coughing
>   They've forgotten, forgotten how to sing, how to sing.
>
> First **there's lights out, then there's lock up**
>   Masterpieces serving **maximum sentences**
>   It's their own fault for being timeless
>   There's a price you pay and a consequence
>   All the galleries, the museums
>   Here's your ticket, welcome to the tombs
>   They're just public mausoleums
>   Here's your ticket, welcome to the tombs
>   They're just public mausoleums
>   **The living dead** fill every room
>
> But the most special are the most lonely
>   God, I pity the violins
>   In **glass coffins** they keep coughing
>   They've forgotten, forgotten how to sing
>
> -- [Regina Spektor,  *All the Rowboats*](https://genius.com/Regina-spektor-all-the-rowboats-lyrics)

Why does she say the works of art are serving **maximum sentences**?

What are the **glass coffins**?

What does **there's lights out, then there's lock up** mean?

What is OR Who are **the living dead**?

Comment: A perfect description of the Ashmoleam collection: https://www.ashmolean.org/musical-instruments. Exactly what I felt when seeing them there.

Comment: Glass coffins, are they a good idea? Remains to be seen.

Comment: @LiefdeWen [rimshot](https://media.giphy.com/media/SUeUCn53naadO/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The songwriter is mixing *mausoleum* and *prison* metaphors.

The "glass coffins" are the cases in which the (presumably) priceless violins are stored and (presumably) never played.  The "living dead" are the instruments which should be played, but instead are kept on display, never making music.

Combined that with the prison image of "lights out" (time for the museum to close) and "lock up" (the violins are locked away like prisoners).  "Maximum sentences" implies the violins are to be locked away forever.

As for whether she is *really* talking about encased instruments, or whether it's a more complicated metaphor -- I leave that to your interpretation.

Comment: Are the *living dead* just that *instruments*? I wonder if they can also be those *imprisoned and captive people in the paintings*.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi  there's a certain degree of *ambiguity* to almost any music or poetry, but in this case while Spektor mentions the other works of art in the museum, she mostly focuses on the glass-cased musical instruments.  I expect this is because they are meant to be a metaphor for something.

Answer (score 6):

Simplistic interpretation here.

It’s a museum and the violins are kept in display cases, forever (or until they’re taken off of display).

Museums have opening hours, so there are "lights out" and "lock up" times (like a prison) when the museum is closed to the public.

Display cases are usually glass. Everyone can see the objects. The objects cannot be touched, only looked at. This is very hard on objects like the violins whose primary purpose is not to be seen, but to be used to make music. Here they remain untouched but unplayed. If they were played, they may be damaged, but in a glass case they will last a long time ("maximum sentence").

The phrase "living dead" applies to the instruments in display cases. They are still playable and a musician could "bring them to life" but not while they’re trapped in display cases.